# How to add tooltip in chart for x category field label in EXTJS 6.5.x

Tags: extjs, extjs6-classic, extjs6.5, extjs6.5.1

I am using EXTJs 6.5. I have designed a bar chart in which the x-axis category label length is too big which overlaps the label. So for a temporary fix, I have added below code to trim the value to 15 characters to show the values postfix with three dots.

```
{
type: 'category',
position: 'bottom',
fields: 'name',
renderer: function(item, label, lastLabel) {
  return Ext.util.Format.ellipsis(label, 15);
}
```

The issue I am facing is that I am not able to add any Html content for the label for example to word wrap the label or to add any tooltip.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**1. Styling**

Although limited, styles can be added to the chart label. Full options [here](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.chart.sprite.Label.html).

Example (tested in this [documentation fiddle](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.chart.axis.Category.html)):

```html
axes: {
    type: 'category',
    position: 'bottom',
    fields: ['name'],
    label: {
    rotation: 270,
    color: 'red'
  },
    title: {
        text: 'Sample Values',
        fontSize: 15
    }
 },
```

**2. Tooltip**

To add a tooltip to your label, you could do something like this:

(code snippet edited to fit you needs)

```html
renderer: function(item, label, lastLabel) {
  var trimmedLabel = Ext.util.Format.ellipsis(label, 15);

  return Ext.String.format("<div data-qtip="{0}">{1}</div>", label, trimmedLabel);
}
```

Comment: By applying the tooltip code solution, I am getting **Uncaught ReferenceError: tooltip is not defined**

Comment: Well yes, you need to define the tooltip variable and adjust it as you like.

Comment: Can you please help me where I have to define that. Sorry to bother you but can't able to figure it out.

Comment: @Mani this is a your full label. Without fromating. Just a string

Comment: @pvlt didn't get you.

Comment: @Mani, I edited the code snippet. I believe you wanted to achieve something like this.

Comment: It didn't work out, it shows the output as undefined.

Comment: For further assistance, please provide a working fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/

Comment: @Mani: If the solution helped you after all, please accept the answer.

Comment: @ground_call sorry to say but in my codebase, the solution didn't work and I didn't get much time to put the sample code in fiddle. We just change the requirement and didn't implement this.